# SQL Query Problem in Joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql

I'm quite new to SQL and PHP and tried two write an array into the database, but I couldn't figure it out so far I always get following Error:

> 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list' SQL=UPDATE #__typsys SET usergroup = Array WHERE userid = 687

I tried it this way:

```
// Get an Array with all the Usergroups the user is in
$usergroups = JFactory::getUser()->getAuthorisedGroups();

// Building the updatequery
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
    ->update($db->quoteName('#__typsys'))
    ->set($db->quoteName(usergroup) . ' = ' . $db->quote($usergroups))
    ->where($db->quoteName('userid') . ' = ' . $user->id)
;
// Executing the updatequery
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

If I write a normal string like "test" in the database everything works fine, but not with an array. I have searched for hours now, but didn't find any solution. Help is much appreciated!!!

Thx in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `$usergroups` returns an array and not a single value. It returns you the usergroup id which the login user belongs to. Like if the current user belongs to `Registered` and `Administrator` group it will return the ids of them as an array.

For this, you have the following option:

```
// Get an Array with all the Usergroups the user is in
$usergroups = JFactory::getUser()->getAuthorisedGroups(); // returns Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 8 )
$usergroups_str = implode(',',$usergroups); // returns (1,8)

// Building the updatequery
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
    ->update($db->quoteName('#__typsys'))
    ->set($db->quoteName(usergroup) . ' = ' . $db->quote($usergroups_str))
    ->where($db->quoteName('userid') . ' = ' . $user->id)
;
// Executing the updatequery
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

This will update the table row for logged in user with all his access levels. Also, I would suggest not to update the `usergroup` column with the `usergroup name` example `Registered`. And while fetching, you can simply explode it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thx I "impolded" it now and saved it in the database. I will "explode" it again and have my array back (to search in it for sorting issues) when I use it for other purposes.

Comment: good to hear this :)